# how do I remove css background-color after it's been declared?

Tags: css

I have a strange situation that I can't fix.  If you view this page, the "Shop" section has that translucent blue-green background:
http://rattletree.com/shop/

It is set with the `#left-area` ID.  However on this page:
http://rattletree.com/the-earth-loves-you-2/

it is also using a `#left-area` ID but it is higher on the page so is taking over the whole background.  I don't see a way to simply remove the background CSS from that one page `#left-area` ID without it removing both.  I tried to do a `background-color:transparent` on a later ID on that second page, but i think that in that case "transparent" doesn't remove the initial background color.  This is on a wordpress install and is using template pages with Woocommerce so it's a little hard for me to get in there and hardcode more ID tags without the possibility of it being overwritten later by an update...any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If `background-color:transparent` overrides it, why do you need it removed? I tried "transparent" and it looks like it will work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a more targeted CSS rule (in addition to existing one) like this `body.single-post div#left-area { background-color: transparent; }` which will take precedence over `#left-area` rule.

I didn't want to reserve to this but the `<body>` tag has a lot of classes specific to the second page (like "post") which you can use to target as well.

Comment: That's what's frustrating-they both have #content-area as well.

Comment: I see, so why does just applying background-color: transparent on the second page not work for you as a solution?

Comment: @Joel I updated my answer to use body tag then class to target your second page. Try that.